# Periodicity of combination of trigonometric functions and more

Tags: trigonometry

I have a math problems which I'm having difficulties with. It's a part of pre-college revision, but we haven't done anything similar in high school. We have a ppt explaining this, but they made it very unclear so I can't understand much.

Basically, this is the function I'm presented with:
$$
\bigl(\sin(2x)+\cos(2x)\bigr)^2
$$

The problem wants me to:

1) determine whether the function is even or odd --> I know this one, no problems

2) determine whether it's periodical = I've looked up some questions here on stackexchange but can't seem to apply it to this specific function. I don't know what to do when the whole function goes to the power of $2$. I also need to determine its period if it's periodical. How exactly do I do this

3) find the zeros of the function --> unclear on how should I do this

4) sketch the graph of the function --> again, I don't know what to do when I have both sin and cos in one function.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Check out compound angle transformations: https://revisionmaths.com/advanced-level-maths-revision/pure-maths/trigonometry/compound-angle-formulae, and start with $r\cos(x-\alpha)$ or similar

Answer (score 1):

2) A function is periodical if there exists a $P$ such that for any real number $x$, $f(x) = f(x+P)$ Note that if $f$ is periodical, $f(x) = f(x+P)$ for any real number $x$, so it follows that $(f(x))^2 = (f(x+P))^2$ for any real number $x$. Hence, if you can show that $sin(2x) + cos(2x)$ is periodical, it follows that $(sin(2x) + cos(2x))^2$ is periodical

3) Similarly, $f(x) = 0 \iff (f(x))^2 = 0$. If you can find the zeros of $sin(2x) + cos(2x)$, then you found the zeros of $(sin(2x) + cos(2x))^2$.

4) Sketching is never my strong suit, but I'll try to give my best: You already know the zeros of the function. You know that it is periodic and what period it has. Determine extrema of the function, and try to realize what the square does to the function. It should look like this: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(sin(2x)+%2B+cos(2x))%5E2+plot

Answer (score 0):

Since sine and cosine have period $2\pi$, the functions $\sin2x$ and $\cos2x$ have period $\pi$. Thus $\pi$ is certainly *a* period for $f(x)=(\sin2x+\cos2x)^2$, but you want to determine the *minimum* period.

Rewrite the function by expanding the square:
$$
f(x)=\sin^22x+2\sin2x\cos2x+\cos^22x=1+2\sin2x\cos2x=1+\sin4x
$$

I guess you'll now be able to do all the required steps.

Comment: Okay, sketching the graph will be a piece of cake now. But how exactly are the zeroes of trigonometrical functions generally found?